# How to order a nested collection by a nested property using SPRING DATA and JPA

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I would like to fetch an entity which collection is ordered by a nested property

```
class Person {

 @OneToMany
 private List<HobbyPerson> hobbies = new ArrayList<>();

}

class HobbyPerson {

 @ManyToOne
 private person Person;

 @ManyToOne
 private hobby Hobby;
}

class Hobby{

 private String name;

 @OneToMany
 private List<HobbyPerson> hobbies = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Whenever I fetch a person by id  (`personRepository.findbyId(person_id)`) I would like to get only one person whose hobbies are ordered by the hobby name

I have tried to use spring data methodnames, @Query annotation but neither worked.

spring data method:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.sample-app.finders.strategies
It seems only ordering of the main entity can be achieved

@Query annotation:
Doesnt support ordering on nested property

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use a `SortedSet` with a comparator or make `HobbyPerson` comparable, like this:

```java
class Person {

 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
 private SortedSet<HobbyPerson> hobbies = new TreeSet<>();

}

class HobbyPerson implements Comparable<HobbyPerson> {

 @ManyToOne
 private Person person;

 @ManyToOne
 private Hobby hobby;

 public int compareTo(HobbyPerson other) {
  return hobby.getName().compareTo(other.getHobby().getName());
 }
}

class Hobby{

 private String name;

 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "hobby")
 private List<HobbyPerson> hobbies = new ArrayList<>();
}
```